# I got a force close when adding table row programatically?

Tags: android

HI am doing table layout programatically for that when i add table row to the layout application shows force close can any body help me and following is my code

```
TableLayout tl = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.maintable);
    TableRow tr = new TableRow(this);
    TextView labelTV = new TextView(this);
    TextView valueTV = new TextView(this);
    // Go through each item in the array
    for (int current = 0; current < numProvinces; current++)
    {
        // Create a TableRow and give it an ID

        tr.setId(100+current);
        tr.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(
                LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));   

        // Create a TextView to house the name of the province

        labelTV.setId(200+current);
        labelTV.setText(provinces[current]);
        labelTV.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
        labelTV.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(
                LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        tr.addView(labelTV);

        // Create a TextView to house the value of the after-tax income

        valueTV.setId(current);
        valueTV.setText("$0");
        valueTV.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
        valueTV.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(
                LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        tr.addView(valueTV);

        // Add the TableRow to the TableLayout
        tl.addView(tr,new TableLayout.LayoutParams(
                LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        setContentView(tl);   
    }
```

Comment: Please write your complete stack trace for more information about the exception.

Comment: Can you give the logcat output ?

Comment: while asking answers for any exceptions, try to post error Log. It's more useful to resolve that.

Answer (score 0):

The view already exist may be the Exception you are getting so,

```
TableRow tr = new TableRow(this);
```

add the above line in side for loop..

This is happening because you are trying to add same TableRow again and again..

**Updated:**
try this

```
tl.addView(tr);
```

instead of

```
tl.addView(tr,new TableLayout.LayoutParams(
                LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
```

Comment: Thank you for helping but i already added that line inside the for loop again its force close

Comment: @santosh .. open your **ddms** you will find reasons causing force close (stack trace).. post it.. we can understand the problem better..

Comment: A null pointer exception at tl.addView(tr,new TableLayout.LayoutParams( LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT)); pls give me suggestion

Answer (score 0):

```
TableLayout tl = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.maintable);
TableRow[] tr;
TextView[] labelTV;
TextView[] valueTV;

tr = new TableRow[numProvinces];
labelTV = new TextView[numProvinces];
valueTV= new TextView[numProvinces];

tl.removeAllViews();
tl.refreshdrawablestate();

for (int current = 0; current < numProvinces; current++)
{      
   tr[current] = new TableRow(this);
   labelTV[current] = new TextView(this);
   labelTV[current] = new TextView(this);

// Create a TableRow and give it an ID

    tr.setId(100+current);
    tr.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(
            LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
            LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));   

    // Create a TextView to house the name of the province

    labelTV.setId(200+current);
    labelTV.setText(provinces[current]);
    labelTV.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
    labelTV.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(
            LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
            LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    tr.addView(labelTV);

    // Create a TextView to house the value of the after-tax income

    valueTV.setId(current);
    valueTV.setText("$0");
    valueTV.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
    valueTV.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(
            LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
            LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    tr.addView(valueTV);

    // Add the TableRow to the TableLayout
    tl.addView(tr,new TableLayout.LayoutParams(
            LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
            LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

}
  setContentView(tl);
```

Comment: i tried with the above code but again it shows force close as a null pointer exception at   tl.addView(tr,new TableLayout.LayoutParams(
            LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
            LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT)); pls give me suggestion

Comment: try this tl.addView(tr,new TableRow.LayoutParams(
            LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
            LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

Answer (score 0):

```
TableLayout tl = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.maintable);

for (int current = 0; current < numProvinces; current++)
{

    TableRow tr = new TableRow(this);
    TextView labelTV = new TextView(this);
    TextView valueTV = new TextView(this);   


    /// Do your stuff   


        tr.addView(labelTV );
        tr.addView(valueTV );

        tbl.addView(tr);    


}
```

Try this answer

Comment: i tried with the above code but again it shows force close as a null pointer exception at tl.addView(tr,new TableLayout.LayoutParams( LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT)); pls give me suggestion

Comment: NULL POINTER EXCEPTION AT tl.addView(); line in the above posted code

Comment: TRY THIS LINK IT WILL HELP YOU  http://www.warriorpoint.com/blog/2009/07/01/android-creating-tablerow-rows-inside-a-tablelayout-programatically/

Answer (score 0):

I tested your code with a change in xml file and it work. I post my code so that you can compare with your own one.
I copy your code:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    //I add some data for test here:

    int numProvinces = 5;
    String[] provinces =new String[]{"1","2","3","4","5"};

    //below is the same with your code:

    TableLayout tl = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.maintable);
    // Go through each item in the array
    for (int current = 0; current < numProvinces; current++)
    {
        TableRow tr = new TableRow(this);
        TextView labelTV = new TextView(this);
        TextView valueTV = new TextView(this);
        // Create a TableRow and give it an ID

        tr.setId(100+current);
        tr.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(
                LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));   

        // Create a TextView to house the name of the province

        labelTV.setId(200+current);
        labelTV.setText(provinces[current]);
        labelTV.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
        labelTV.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(
                LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        tr.addView(labelTV);

        // Create a TextView to house the value of the after-tax income

        valueTV.setId(current);
        valueTV.setText("$0");
        valueTV.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
        valueTV.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(
                LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        tr.addView(valueTV);

        // Add the TableRow to the TableLayout
        tl.addView(tr,new TableLayout.LayoutParams(
                LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        setContentView(tl);   
    }
```

}

and this is my main layout (main.xml)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

        android:id="@+id/maintable"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

/>
```

Comment: i tried by using this xml also but it shows null pointer exception at tl.addView();  line in the above posted code pls suggest to me